# When the form is submitted, the selected item is cleared

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I use flask,when I click the `submit` button,the selected item(`id=workingMethod`) I chose is emptied.

I select `2`,you can see it in this picture:

[image]

When I click the `submit` button:

[image]

How can I keep the content I choose in select?

My HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>cal</title>
        <link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="static/css/FlaskModelCalculation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="static/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="static/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
              $('#calculate').click(function(){
              var careerHistory = $("#careerHistory").val();
              if(careerHistory=="" || careerHistory==="undefined"){
                    alert("careerHistory cann't null");
                    return;
                 }
              });
        });
    </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center" style="margin-top:60px">
            <form name="form1" method='POST'>
                    <span>careerHistory</span><input type="text" placeholder="careerHistory" id="careerHistory" name="careerHistory" class="form-control" value="{{careerHistory}}"><br/>
                    <span>wholeBookNumber</span><input type="text" placeholder="wholeBookNumber" id="wholeBookNumber" name="wholeBookNumber"  class="form-control" value="{{wholeBookNumber}}"><br/>
                    <span>reflectionBookNumber</span><input type="text" placeholder="reflectionBookNumber" id="reflectionBookNumber" name="reflectionBookNumber"  class="form-control" value="{{reflectionBookNumber}}"><br/>
                    <span>schoolClassificationCD</span><input type="text" placeholder="schoolClassificationCD" id="schoolClassificationCD" name="schoolClassificationCD" class="form-control" value="{{schoolClassificationCD}}"><br/>
                    <span>jobsNumber</span><input type="text" placeholder="jobsNumber" id="jobsNumber" name="jobsNumber"  class="form-control" value="{{jobsNumber}}"><br/>
                    <span>constructionSpecificity</span><input type="text" placeholder="constructionSpecificity" id="constructionSpecificity" name="constructionSpecificity"  class="form-control" value="{{constructionSpecificity}}"><br/>
                    <span>playingStyle</span><input type="text" placeholder="playingStyle" id="playingStyle" name="playingStyle"  class="form-control" value="{{playingStyle}}"><br/>
                    <span>workingMethod</span>
                        <select id="workingMethod" name="workingMethod" class="">
                            <option value ="0"></option>
                            <option value ="1">1</option>
                            <option value ="2">2</option>
                            <option value ="3">3</option>
                        </select><br/>
                    <span>workOvertimeAverage</span><input type="text" placeholder="workOvertimeAverage" id="workOvertimeAverage" name="workOvertimeAverage" class="form-control" value="{{workOvertimeAverage}}"><br/>
                    <input type="submit" id="calculate" class="btn btnNormal btn-primary" value="cal">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="calculationResult" name="calculationResult" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" value="{{calculationResult}}">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Python Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import redirect
from flask import url_for
from flask import request
import Store_mold

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('calculate'))

@app.route('/calculate',methods=['GET','POST'])
def calculate():
    if request.method =="POST":
        careerHistory = int(request.form['careerHistory'])
        wholeBookNumber = int(request.form['wholeBookNumber'])
        reflectionBookNumber = int(request.form['reflectionBookNumber'])
        schoolClassificationCD = int(request.form['schoolClassificationCD'])
        jobsNumber = int(request.form['jobsNumber'])
        constructionSpecificity = int(request.form['constructionSpecificity'])
        playingStyle = int(request.form['playingStyle'])
        workingMethod = int(request.form.get('workingMethod'))
        workOvertimeAverage = int(request.form['workOvertimeAverage'])
        calculationResult = int(Store_mold.Store_mold(careerHistory,wholeBookNumber,reflectionBookNumber,schoolClassificationCD,jobsNumber,constructionSpecificity,playingStyle,workingMethod,workOvertimeAverage))
        if calculationResult==0:
            calculationResult='yes'
        elif calculationResult==1:
            calculationResult='no'
        return render_template('index.html',careerHistory=careerHistory, wholeBookNumber=wholeBookNumber, reflectionBookNumber=reflectionBookNumber, schoolClassificationCD=schoolClassificationCD, jobsNumber=jobsNumber, constructionSpecificity=constructionSpecificity, playingStyle=playingStyle, workingMethod=workingMethod, workOvertimeAverage=workOvertimeAverage, calculationResult=calculationResult)
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I think I should use sessionStorage to do this,save the select option value to sessionStorage,after each click, get the value from sessionStorage and set it to select option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use sessionStorage to do this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            var ss_schoolClassificationCD = sessionStorage.getItem("schoolClassificationCD");
            if($.trim(ss_schoolClassificationCD)=="" || ss_schoolClassificationCD==="undefined"!="" || schoolClassificationCD!=null){
                $("#schoolClassificationCD").val(ss_schoolClassificationCD);
            }

            var ss_constructionSpecificity = sessionStorage.getItem("constructionSpecificity");
            if($.trim(ss_constructionSpecificity)=="" || ss_constructionSpecificity==="undefined"!="" || ss_constructionSpecificity!=null){
                $("#constructionSpecificity").val(ss_constructionSpecificity);
            }

            var ss_playingStyle = sessionStorage.getItem("playingStyle");
            if($.trim(ss_playingStyle)=="" || ss_playingStyle==="undefined"!="" || ss_playingStyle!=null){
                $("#playingStyle").val(ss_playingStyle);
            }

            var ss_workingMethod = sessionStorage.getItem("workingMethod");
            if($.trim(ss_workingMethod)=="" || ss_workingMethod==="undefined"!="" || ss_workingMethod!=null){
                $("#workingMethod").val(ss_workingMethod);
            }

          $("#calculate").click(function(){
            var careerHistory = $("#careerHistory").val();
            var wholeBookNumber = $("#wholeBookNumber").val();
            var reflectionBookNumber = $("#reflectionBookNumber").val();
            var schoolClassificationCD = $("#schoolClassificationCD").val();
            var jobsNumber = $("#jobsNumber").val();
            var constructionSpecificity = $("#constructionSpecificity").val();
            var playingStyle = $("#playingStyle").val();
            var workingMethod = $("#workingMethod").val();
            var workOvertimeAverage = $("#workOvertimeAverage").val();

             if($.trim(careerHistory)=="" || careerHistory==="undefined"){
                return;
             }else{
                sessionStorage.setItem("careerHistory",careerHistory);
                sessionStorage.setItem("wholeBookNumber",wholeBookNumber);
                sessionStorage.setItem("reflectionBookNumber",reflectionBookNumber);
                sessionStorage.setItem("schoolClassificationCD",schoolClassificationCD);
                sessionStorage.setItem("jobsNumber",jobsNumber);
                sessionStorage.setItem("constructionSpecificity",constructionSpecificity);
                sessionStorage.setItem("playingStyle",playingStyle);
                sessionStorage.setItem("workingMethod",workingMethod);
                sessionStorage.setItem("workOvertimeAverage",workOvertimeAverage);

                $("#form1").submit();
             }

          });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With all of the other fields, you're explicitly setting the value:

```
<input type="text" ... value="{{foo}}">
```

But you aren't doing that with the workingMethod field.

Since it's a `<select>` field and not an `<input type="text">` field like the others, you can't set the value the same way; you have to add a `selected="selected"` attribute to the option that should be selected.

Comment: I use this code `<select id="workingMethod" name="workingMethod" class="" value="{{workingMethod}}">`
It doesn't work.

Comment: What do you expect that code to display? There's no text between the tags. 
 You need to put `0` between the `<option>` and `</option>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

put this inside of calculate on click function after your validation check.

```
var dlval =
$('#workingMethod').children("option:selected").val();
$("#workingMethod").find("option:contains(dlval)").each(function() {
     if( $(this).val() == dlval) {
         $(this).attr("selected","selected");
     }
});
```

Comment: I fixed my code as you said,but when I click `submit` ,the selected item is cleared.

Comment: Got you point. Assumed the page got post back (refresh) when you submit. all you need to store form data into localstorage to repopulate data. Updating my answer in while.

Comment: I think I should use sessionStorage to do this,save the select value to sessionStorage,after each click, get the value from sessionStorage and set it to select option.